# Difference between IPython and Jupyter qtconsole

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I downloaded Anaconda for Windows (Python 2.7). I created two environments with different packages. If I change the environment and launch IPyhon, all packages are available. Since I have other problems with IPython, I tried for the first time Jupyter qtconsole. What is the difference between these? I searched for half a day, but I can't find a proper answer. Are they related? Is something better/newer/etc.?

If I try to import e.g. pandas in Jupyter qtconsole, I get the error message:

```
No module named panda
```

But if I try to install pandas in Jupyter qtconsole: `!pip install pandas`, I get this error message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\...\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\mpcpy\lib\site-packages
```

Hope that someone can help me. Thank you

Comment: you want `import pandas`, not `import panda`

Comment: `qtconsole` seems to be a gui that acts like a terminal (i.e. a console) that allows you to do nifty things like inline plots and figures. IPython is a Python *REPL*. This REPL is running in the `qtconsole`, just as it might run in the windows `cmd` "terminal"

Answer (score 3):

As Tim Gottgetreu noted, there is a typo in the word `import panda`:
It must be `import pandas as pd`. I add `as pd` part, because that is the convention.

To the main question about the difference between Jupyter iPython and Jupyter Qtconsole:

1)iPython is an 'enhanced' 'Terminal' vs. Qtconsole is imitating it by design.

from the docs: https://qtconsole.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

2)Qt console shows docs of objects as a pop-up window, which is very handy. In iPython, I have to use `object.__doc__()` to read the docs.

3)Qt console is good when you work with data and have to plot it, because it already has all the backend drivers loaded and set up within it to support interactive plotting. In iPython you have to do this yourself and it is system depended.

4)iPython has been around for longer and has better integration with different outside sources. QTconsole has some limitations.

5) (personal) I get tired staring at the bottom of the screen to type commands and see output. In QTconsole I can scroll and bring my cursor line to the level (hight) I want, whilst in iPython I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather Jupyter notebook is the next generation of Ipython. Pandas (and Numpy) both come as standard installs with Anaconda. So after you launch Jupyter `! jupyter notebook` in the command line, importing pandas and numpy should be straight forward in juptyer notebook. Standard import being

`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np`

then run the cell by crtl+enter